# Android app development - 2 screen app

Tags: java, android, screen

How can I "connect" 2 screens in Java. When I click on button at first screen that then it opens second screen?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is _exactly_ the same example they use in the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent openSecondScreen = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
startActivity(openSecondScreen);
```